# forbiddenScope Error : while adding person in Google Plus circle via HTTP request

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, google-domain-api

I want to add user in circle. I have retrieved `access_token` as described in [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) with scopes :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write
```

Then i am calling HTTP request as described in [Circles: addPeople](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/addPeople)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/circles/<circleId>/people?userId=<userID>
```

but in response i am getting -

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
   "domain": "plusDomains",
"reason": "forbiddenScope",
"message": "Access to the Google+ Domains API is not allowed as the user has consented to incompatible scopes. See: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/."
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "Access to the Google+ Domains API is not allowed as the user has consented to incompatible scopes. See: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/."
}
}
```

I have enabled **Google+ API**, **Google+ Domains API** in project's [API's & Auth section.](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the [revoking access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521) of the app. It might have been previously granted `plus.login` scope which is incompatible. With Domains API scopes.

Comment: yes tried but no use... getting same error.